# Самый короткий путь (матрица)

Tags: python, c++

Да, матрица, не дерево, т.е. Дейскра тут не катит.

Есть матрица 1000х1000, а вообще она произвольная. Пусть будут координаты 134х444 и 751х199. Собственно как найти между ними самый короткий путь, сколько нужно пройти ячеек между ними.

Язык С++, а лучше python. Хотя мне все равно какой :) Спасибо.

Comment: Вы совершенно не описали задачу.

Если все "ходы" допустимы, то идите по прямой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы действительно описали задачу  неполно. Предположим, что переход по горизонтали равноценен переходу по вертикали. Тогда возможны два варианта.

**Переход по диагонали неразрешен.** Тогда минимально возможная длина пути расчитывается как сумма длин сторон прямоугольника, на которых расположены точки

```
def min_way(x1, y1, x2, y2):    
    return abs(x2-x1)+abs(y2-y1)
```

**Переход по диагонали разрешен** и равноценен переходу по вертикали/горизонтали. Тогда минимальный путь равен длине максимальной стороны

```
def min_way(x1, y1, x2, y2):    
    return max(abs(x2-x1), abs(y2-y1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне по душе c#, на примере сделай :)

```
int[] a = {134, 444};
int[] b = {751, 199};
int s = 0;

while (a != b) {
    if ((a[0] < b[0]) && (a[1] < b[1])) { a[0]++; a[1]++; }
    else if ((a[0] < b[0]) && (a[1] > b[1])) { a[0]++; a[1]--; }
    else if ((a[0] > b[0]) && (a[1] < b[1])) { a[0]--; a[1]++; } 
    else if ((a[0] = b[0]) && (a[1] < b[1])) a[1]++;
    else if ((a[0] = b[0]) && (a[1] > b[1])) a[1]--;
    else if ((a[0] < b[0]) && (a[1] = b[1])) a[0]++;
    else if ((a[0] > b[0]) && (a[1] = b[1])) a[0]--;
    s++;
}

Console.WriteLine(s.toString());
```

Comment: переписал на python, выводит 617, вроде правильно, решил сверить, а c# крутит бесконечный цикл :)))